# Return the right object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to complete a programming exercise but one test fails. What have i done wrong?

The task is:

> Write a program that manages robot factory settings.
>
> When robots come off the factory floor, they have no name.
>
> The first time you boot them up, a random name is generated, such as
>   RX837 or BC811.
>
> Every once in a while we need to reset a robot to its factory
>   settings, which means that their name gets wiped. The next time you
>   ask, it gets a new name.

The tests for the program looks like this and the one that fails is the **Different_robots_have_different_names**:

```
public class RobotNameTest
{
    private Robot robot;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        robot = new Robot();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Robot_has_a_name()
    {
        StringAssert.IsMatch(@"[A-Z]{2}\d{3}", robot.Name);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Name_is_the_same_each_time()
    {
        Assert.That(robot.Name, Is.EqualTo(robot.Name));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Different_robots_have_different_names()
    {
        var robot2 = new Robot();
        Assert.That(robot.Name, Is.Not.EqualTo(robot2.Name));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_reset_the_name()
    {
        var originalName = robot.Name;
        robot.Reset();
        Assert.That(robot.Name, Is.Not.EqualTo(originalName));
    }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class Robot
{
    private List<string> Names = new List<string>();

    private string name { get; set; }
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }

    public Robot()
    {
        CreateName();
    }

    private void CreateName()
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var random = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(
            new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3)
                    .Select(x => x[random.Next(x.Length)]).ToArray()
            )
        );
        sb.Append(random.Next(100, 999));
        if(Names.Any(word => word.Equals(sb.ToString())))
        {
            CreateName();
        }
        else
        {
            name = sb.ToString();
            Names.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.name = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: `What have i done wrong?` you have pasted your code with the minimum of explanation hoping we will do the whole job for you. At first glance, you probably wanted to have `Names` static, if not take into account the overall design of the Robot class

Comment: I don't expect that at all. I have obviously tried to finish the program but i don't understand why that one test fails.

Comment: every time you create Robot object, a new List of Names is being  created, so the line `Names.Any(word => word.Equal` doesn't make much sense to me in this context

Comment: Good point, thank you! I will change the Names list. But that doesn't explain the failing test i think.

Comment: You're missing a test case: Robots should not have a name when instantiated. You have to "boot" the robot to assign it a name. You're not implementing the tests as defined in the spec, and thus your code is incorrect as well. This has nothing to do with your specific problem, but I wanted to point it out -- if you're doing TDD to a spec, you should actually *pay attention* to the spec, otherwise you're going to be writing the wrong tests and the wrong code to back the tests up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making `Names` static passes all the tests:

```
private static List<string> Names = new List<string>();
```

[Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3(v=vs.110).aspx) keyword means that the member is being created on the **class** level, not the object.

In your case **all** Robots would share a link to a **single** list of Names. Removing the static keyword would result in `Names` list being create **per** Robot object. If you want to track how many times Robots constructor has been called, you should probably have a shared list of names, which is shared across all Robot object.

Your tests fails because when second object is created, it has a **new** empty Names list, which first Robot class knows nothing about. So in your case `Names.Any(...)` would always return false.

To read in more details consider msdn link above.

Comment: Yes, but this would not have made the test fail if the random generation was OK (very unlikely to generate the same name both times). So you're right, but the OP should also use Olivier's advice (which, alone, would, as I said, have made the tests pass 99.999 % of the time).

Comment: @PatriceGahide I completely agree with you and Oliver, that's why I've upvoted his answer. There is three problems with this solution: Names being non-static, random being initialized very often (static solves this issue, another one is to inject Random into Robot) and the last problem is the possibility to have StackOverflow Exception because of recursive call there. I agree, that the last problem can only occur in very rare cases

Comment: Assuming that the names list is static, the recursive call of `CreateName` will be called many times until the clock ticks and and another name is generated, and thus hide the problem of random being created too fast and too often.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is not obvious. The `Random` class gets initialized with a random seed created from the current system time. The watch yielding the system time ticks slowly compared to the CPU clock frequency. Therefore it is well possible that `random` gets initialized twice with the same seed if `new Random()` is called to fast twice.

Solution: Declare random as static and initialize it only once.

```
public class Robot
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    ...
}
```

Now `random` is created only once no matter how many robots you create.

Comment: Valid point, but he has a "guard" clause `Names.Any(...)` to duplicated names. Try to run unit tests locally, I think the problem with Random is not the crucial one, but the fact, that each Robot object has it's own `Names` list

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: If the names are truly random this check will rarely have an effect. But you are right, the names list must be `static`. And to be completely correct, the uniqueness test would go into a loop instead of just an `if`.